# put a Button into a frame in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

i am trying template my tkinter application. 
But i cant put buttons into my Frames.

Is Frame the right control for use as a template? 
or is there something different.

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame = Frame(root, height="200", width="200", bg="green").pack()
b = Button(frame, text="Hell World").pack(padx="10", pady="10")

z = Label(root, text="OUTSIDE").pack()

root.mainloop()
```

this is my code.

the code runs, but the button is beneath the green frame. But i want to have this button inside of the frame.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
frame = Frame(root, height="200", width="200", bg="green").pack()
```

After this line executes, `frame` is equal to `None` because that's what `pack()` returns. You need to assign a widget and pack it on separate lines if you want to keep a reference to it.

```
frame = Frame(root, height="200", width="200", bg="green")
frame.pack()
```

Same for `b` and `z`, but you never use them so they don't matter as much.